# It has been 20 hours and my post on Reddit still hasn't shown up

Tags: reddit

I submitted a post to [/r/ImGoingToHellForThis](https://www.reddit.com/r/ImGoingToHellForThis). I've checked on the new tab on the subreddit and the post is nowhere to be found.

Any idea why it seems to be completely off the radar?

Answer (score 5):

Posts on reddit can get flagged by an automatic spam filter.  This tends to happen pretty often to new users to a particular subreddit -- the spam filter is per-subreddit, so you may still be treated as a new user on /r/ImGoingToHellForThis even if you're a regular on another subreddit.

That is the most common cause for post removal.  It could have also been manually removed by a moderator.  In either instance, your best bet for resolution is to message the moderators of that subreddit because they will now need to manually review your post and "Approve" it via moderator tools if they feel it belongs on the subreddit.

Problem with that is that it has been a while since submission, so it won't be in the new queue.  It would also be detrimental to you to delete the post and resubmit, because the spam filter looks for things like that.  Kind of a bummer for this submission, but you'll have a better shot with future submissions if a moderator approves and/or upvotes this current submission.  Just get in contact with a mod, and they'll be able to help you out.

---

Edit: Per the comments, I also wanted to mention that subreddit moderators are given pretty much free reign to do whatever they want, so moderation procedures vary by subreddit.  For example, /r/AskScience has a very large moderation team and moderates comments and questions heavily, but some random subreddit with 25 subscribers and an inactive mod will not have any moderation outside of the automated utilities (like the spam filter).

That means that you can't count on being notified by a moderator if your post is removed, so it's up to you to keep up with that.

Comment: I've been hit by a filter before and a moderator and both times they have either commented on the post telling me why it was deleted or I received mail in my inbox. At the same time, it was never at r/ImGoingToHellForThis so maybe they don't have a setup like that, never thought of that though. Thank you for the advice, I'll go ahead and resubmit it and see if it works this time.

Comment: @user47040 Yeah, and feel free to go ahead and message them if you don't see it after a few minutes.  That way it'll get back out into the wild sooner.  You can accept this answer if it helped by clicking the checkmark next to it. Welcome to Stack Exchange. :)